# How to keep discussions of user in database and show them on view page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem in my crm application,in my application I have a user view page with his details and a add follow up button in which I have 3 text fields used to maintain follow-up records of a user and show dis follow-up details in view page . How can I achieve it?

Here's my *view.php* page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?php  require_once ("sqlremote.php");
$sql="Select * from ac_member order by rand() limit 15";
$res=$db->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();
$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
 ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;  
   }
}
</script>
<style>
.top-section{height:87px; padding-bottom:10px;}
.logo{width:266px; height:87px; float:left;}

body {
    background-image: url(images/hd_wall_4472.jpg);
</style>
</head>
   <body  oncontextmenu="return false">  
<div class="logo"><a href="./"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="200" height="78" border="0" /></a></div>   

</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
        <form action="process.php" method="post" class="register">
        <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend>Basic Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Date
                    </label>
                    <input name="fname" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['datepicker']?>"/>
                    <label>Full Name
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  value="<?php echo $row['fname'] ?>"/>
                    <label>Qualification 
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['qualification'] ?>"/>

                </p>
                <p>
                <label>Father Name  
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['gname'] ?>"/>
                <label>Email
                    </label>
                    <input name="contact" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>"/>
                <label>Contact
                    </label>
                    <input name="contact" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['contact'] ?>"/>

                </p>
                <p> 
                <label>City  
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['city'] ?>"/>
                <label>Course  
                     </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['course'] ?>"/>

                </p>        
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
            </br></br>

            <fieldset class="row1">
           <legend>Lead Info</legend>
           <p>
                    <label>Lead Source
                    </label>
                    <input name="leadsource" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['leadsource']?>"/>
                    <label>Lead Source Type
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  value="<?php echo $row['leadsourcetype'] ?>"/>

                </p>
           <p>
           <label>Lead Source Detail  
                    </label>
                    <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['leadsourcedetail'] ?>"/>
           <label>Lead Score
                     </label>
                     <input name="leadscore" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['leadscore']?>"/>
           </p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset> 

            <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Followup Details</legend>
                <p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add Followup" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Followup" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
                </p>
              <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Followup</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="BX_age">Followup Calldisposition</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_age[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="BX_gender">Followup Comments</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="BX_gender[]" required="required">
                         </td>
                            </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset> 
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />  
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
    </br>
   </body>
<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=9046834; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="ec55ba17"; 
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://secure." : "http://www.");
document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
scJsHost+
"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
</script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="free hit
counter" href="http://statcounter.com/" target="_blank"><img
class="statcounter"
src="http://c.statcounter.com/9046834/0/ec55ba17/1/"
alt="free hit counter"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understand your question correct. Is this a database/query related issue or more a strategic question of what is considered best practise?

Im not really sure what youre trying to accomplish here :)

Comment: i have 3 text fields in this user view page, what i am trying to do is after enterring data in text fields i want to save them in mysql database and show those details in that view page after submitting

Comment: yeah but problem is how to keep individual user followup datails in database and to retrive those individual user followup details in their page

Answer (score 0):

Ah :)

So actually you would grab your data gotten from you select first. Which you are already doing.

process.php:

```
if ($everythingisok) {
    $res=$db->prepare("UPDATE ac_member SET bx_gender='".$_POST["BX_gender"]."', field2=etc... WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'");
    $res->execute();
}
```

After storing the data into the table you can add to your html/view:

```
<input type="text"  name="BX_gender" value="<?php echo escape($row['bx_gender']);?>" required="required">
```

However, i noticed that you are using the brackets in your input name. This will cause that the data coming through is passed as an array. I don't know if you did this on purpose

Comment: can i keep these followup details of each user sepereately in another table in database

Comment: I edited the update query so you can see how to achieve updating one database record in a table